# Align divs with p external to those divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

I have a div with some p's inside and want to put buttons to the side of some p's. Only some of the buttons show up, and I will control which ones through Javascript. Usually, I would put each p in a different wrapper div, which would also contains the corresponding button. BUT I want a background image around all p's, so I need to put all p's inside the same div and can't have separate div's for each p. I also don't want the background to appear around the buttons, which will be round. How do I align the buttons with the p's? Should I use jQuery to get the top properties of each p and pass them on to the buttons?

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bw22yht1/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="p-wrapper">
            <!--there is a background image here-->
            <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.content
{
    width:1100px;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left: 200px; 
}
.p-wrapper
{
    background-image:url('bg/old-paper-texture.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-left:25px;
    font-size:20pt;
    margin:0px 0px 10px;
    width:700px;
}
```

actual page: http://cin.ufpe.br/~rvcam/map/
**EDIT:** An image that shows what I need:
[image: desired output]

Comment: What do you mean 'align the buttons with the p element'?

Comment: @manassorn I mean that, depending on the size of the paragraph, it may span multiple lines. I would like each button to appear right next to its corresponding paragraph, not above nor below.

Comment: What do you mean *"I also don't want the background to appear behind the buttons"*? buttons are not transparent.

Comment: @TJ I mean around them. I want the background to be only applied to the text, not the buttons. The buttons will be round and I want the square in which the buttons are contained to be white.

Comment: @TJ I added an image that shows what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look to your page, and you simply need to change your approach

```
<div class="content">
        <ol class="p-wrapper">
            <!--there is a background image here-->
            <li>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</li>

        </ol>
    </div>
```

You'll have what you need AND no need for that additional span, you'll have automatic numering

**EDIT**: See code below to fit your needs.

**HTML** mostly remains the same, just change  `<ol class="p-wrapper">` to `<ol class="bible">` and add buttons

```
<div class="content">
            <ol class="bible">
                <!--there is a background image here-->
                <li><div class="bibletext">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div> <div class="but"><button></button></div></li>
                <li><div class="bibletext">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div></li>
                <li><div class="bibletext">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div><div class="but"><button></button></div></li>

            </ol>
        </div>
```

**CSS** as follows:

```
.content
{
    width:1100px;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background:url('bg/old-paper-texture.jpg') repeat-y;
    background-size:700px; /* your current .bible width */  
}
.bible
{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-left:25px;
    font-size:20pt;
    margin:0px 0px 10px;
    width:700px;
    color: white;
    /*box-shadow:-30px 30px 30px #888888;*/
}
.bible li{position:relative; width:800px} /*700 px + button width, change at will */
.bibletext{width:700px}
.but{width:100px; position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}
```

Then you'll need some adjustments to fit your taste, but this will work just as you want

Comment: So, to add a button, I put the div inside the li? If I do that, won't the background image cover the button as well?

Comment: yes, you put the button inside the `li`, and no, the background won't cover anything since it will be 1 layer below the `li`

Comment: I'm sorry, I chose my words poorly. I meant to say the background would also appear behind the button. I want the background to appear only behind the text.

Comment: I added an image that shows what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: That really solved the problem, but created others. For example, there's a "reference" div at the bottom of the page. I put overflow:hidden to make the content div include the reference one (which I don't uderstand well, because overflow:hidden should make stuff disappear, not stretch the external div, but that's another question). By taking out the overflow:hidden code, the reference div is not included in the background. This is a minor problem, since I could modify the design to leave it outside anyway. The second problem is repeat-y. (next comment)

Comment: Using repeat-y, the image breaks in the middle to start another one (you can see that in the page now, near the bottom). This is specially worrying because the size of the text may vary. The last, smallest /problem, is that the text appears in front of the gray header. To solve this, I only have to change z-index.

Comment: Oh,and I think there is another issue: the background doesn't seem to stop at 700px. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: yes, you changed a lot from the code I gave you. For the background issue, try this: `background:url('bg/old-paper-texture.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:800px 100%; ` and now you'll have it covering everything you need yet leaving those buttons out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59700/discussion-between-rvcam-and-fabio).

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position a `<div>` with white background containing the `<button>` aside   the `<p>` in a common `<div>` as follows:

```
  <div class="demo">
      <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <div class="right">
           <button>Button</button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

`<div>`'s are transparent by default so having a common parent `<div>` won't hide the background of the wrapper.

You can then align the button using following:

CSS:

```
p {
  margin-right:200px;
}
.demo {
  position:relative;
}
.right {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:200px;
  background:white;
}
.demo button {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bw22yht1/5/)